# generate random instances with JAXB

Tags: java, testing, random, jaxb, instance

I'm using JABX to generate a tree of classes from a big schema, and then read/write instances of this schema.

Now, to bullet-proof my application, I'd like to have JAXB (or some other tool) to generate many random instances of that schema, that I can feed in my application.
This way I would be able to see if my application crashes for some input data.

I'm expecting that JAXB, with only the cardinality and default values at each nodes, be able to generate itself an instance of the tree.

Do you think it's feasible with JAXB? Do you have other ideas?

Comment: Please [don't use signatures or taglines](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures) in your posts.

Comment: This wouldn't be a function of JAXB, however hopefully there is a tool/library that generates valid docs for an XML schema.  I believe XML Spy by Altova has this capability.

Comment: This is where I would turn to unit testing. Pass in the data directly to the objects and not use xml to test your business logic. We should be pretty confident that JAXB does what it says it does. So just call the objects method that takes the unmarshalled xml objects. Then create a few utils that generate random data to feed it.

Comment: Thanks for your response Kodova. That's what I'm doing right now.
But that was not my question: I wanted to save all that effort of writing unit tests by generating problematically and randomly a valid object tree.

Answer (score 0):

XMLBeans has such a tool: [xsd2inst](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/guide/tools.html#xsd2inst)